# Flask-login redirecting back to login page

Tags: flask, pycharm, flask-login, flask-mongoengine

I am writing a simple flask app using flask-login and flask-mongoengine, everything was working fine until I updated all of the python plugins that I need for the project.  Now flask won't log me in.  When I login and the form is validated, it returns me to the login page, with the url: http://localhost:5000/auth/login?next=%2Findex ... I think the `%2F` might have something to do with the issue.

Here is my login view:

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.objects(username__exact=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash(_('Invalid username or password'))
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('main.index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('auth/login.html', title=_('Sign In'), form=form)
```

I'm using WTForms and I can confirm that the form `action=""`

This is adapted from the flask megatutorial, but I'm using MongoDB.

Comment: When you attempt to login what sort of error messages do you receive? Was the database reset such that the User table was dropped and there's no more valid users?

Comment: I don’t receive any errors, which makes this difficult.  When I run the function thru the debugger, it is getting a valid user. next_page gets the value ‘/‘ and then gets passed to the redirect function. The redirect function is redirecting back to the login page instead of ‘/index’ or ‘/‘

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!

When I was converting the app from using SQL to MongoDB, I incorrectly made the load_user function like:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    return User.objects(username__exact=username).first()
```

But in reality the load_user function needs to accept the `id` field as an interface, so the function should look like:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.objects.get(id=id)
```